# In Windows 10 Console run a "PORT"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Wie führe ich in der normalen Windows 10 Console ein "Port" aus bzw. das hier: "PORT=3001 node bin/www"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is written in German. Stack Overflow is an english site. Translate or find a german equivalent

Answer (score 0):

First you install NodeJS.

Then save the file to Copy the file to C:\ for example.

Then create C:\myapp.js

Then

```
  var http = require('http');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello\n');
  }).listen(3001, "127.0.0.1");
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3001/');
```

Then go Start -> Run... -> cmd

Navigate to c: and do C:>node myapp.js

This is the most raw example I could come up with, but it is better to simply use Express in an editor like Visual Studio Code and run a terminal in there.